# page has two php files with identical names how to wget the correct php file? adding identifier?

Tags: php, regex, wget, fiddler, wireshark

I have this problem when I'm trying to use `wget` to retrieve the OUTPUT of a specific php script, but it looks like this site generates 2 identical PHP files.

The 1st one is smaller and the 2nd one, in the sequence, is the correct one. The problem is every time I try the `wget` command, I end-up with the smallest output file, which does not contain the desired info :(

Is there a way to download the correct file, using `wget`, by adding some sort of identifier to the link, to make sure I'm downloading the correct file.

Here is the command I've been trying:

```
$ wget http://www.fernsehen.to/index.php
```

If your run/play this and use Fidller or Wireshark for capture, you'll end-up with two (2) "http://www.fernsehen.to/index.php" and I need the bigger file of the two.

P.S. To manually get the desired output file, you can open http://www.fernsehen.to/index.php in Firefox or chrome and view source.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the first response is not a redirect? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection)

Comment: That's a good point, but I'm not exactly sure. Fiddler shows two files with the exact same name and I need to point to one only. Apparently wget uses the 1st one :(

Answer (score 3):

What you want is not really practically possible. When you visit that page, they first generate a small file with a load of Javascript, that detects browser features and sends them back to the server in a stateful manner in order to produce the exact code required for your browser, probably including stuff like supported codecs for video mainly. Probably they also do some session fingerprinting for DRM purposes, to stop people like you from exactly what you're trying to do.

`wget` cannot emulate this behaviour because it is not a full browser, and cannot execute all that Javascript, nor if it did properly supply browser-like data. You'd have to write an extensive piece of custom code that exactly mimics everything the *in-between* page is doing to achieve the intended effect. Possible, but not easy, and most certainly not with a basic generic-purpose tool like `wget`.

Comment: Thanks Niels! I have come across a similar situation where 2 files are generated with the exact same name, and to get to the right one, I had to add an identifier (found in the request page) to the the actual php link and that seemed to have done the trick. In this particular  case, I'm puzzled!!!

Comment: Well they can do anything inside the page - set cookies, generate identifiers and everything. Like I said, it's always possible, but usually situations like these are a lot harder than 'just adding an identifier'.